# Why does my FontSquirrel font not work?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I am trying to use a font I have downloaded from http://www.fontsquirrel.com/. The files I have attached are included in the fonts folder and in my HTML file I have an `<h1>` tag that says "Hello font".

However it does not work. Does anyone know why?

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'vitaminregular';
    src: url('fotns/VITAMIN_-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/VITAMIN_-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded- opentype'), url('fonts/VITAMIN_-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/VITAMIN_-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/VITAMIN_-webfont.svg#vitaminregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
h1 {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:100px;
    font-family:'VitaminRegular;
}
```

Comment: Your second line in `@font-face` has fonts spelled `fotns`.

Answer (score 2):

```
h1{

                  text-align:center;
                  font-size:100px;
                  font-family:'VitaminRegular;
                       }
```

Your font-family call in H1 is missing a closing '

Change the call to

```
font-family:'VitaminRegular';
```

And this should work

Answer (score 0):

```
    @font-face {
    font-family:'vitaminregular';
    src: url('fotns/VITAMIN_-webfont.eot');
    src: url('fonts/VITAMIN_-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded- opentype'), url('fonts/VITAMIN_-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/VITAMIN_-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/VITAMIN_-webfont.svg#vitaminregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
h1 {
    text-align:center;
    font-size:100px;
    font-family:'vitaminRegular';
}
```

In the h1, font font-family should match @font-face font family property